# Tearing in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: video-player, gpu-driver, tearing

I have tearing problem in Xubuntu 14.04 (both 64 and 32 bit)

[image: first screen shot]
[image: second screen shot]
[image: third screen shot]

I'm using an Aspire s3:
http://www.itp.net/587066-acer-aspire-s3-ms2346?tab=specs

I have already installed the Intel driver but the tearing is present in every video player i use, how do i enable vertical sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable vsync you first need to enable xfce composite in the Window Manager Settings:

[image]

Comment: it's already enabled http://postimg.org/image/o5d31heqd/

Comment: Now you only miss to check Synchronize rawing to the vertical line, vsync. @PhantomFav

Comment: thank you, that was the problem, maybe you can remark to check this option in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I added a ppa from https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers and updated my system.

I then added below lines to file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Intel Graphics"
Driver "intel"
Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

and restarted the System.

Now my system(with Intel graphics) is completely tear free and can use 'compositing' from "windows manager tweaks".

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to try Compton if standard tear-free option did not help you. It is Xcompmgr fork.

http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/

I am using it with Nvidia, should work with Intel too. Do you have problem only in video or also in DE? In first case try other video drivers output in video player settings.